# Passive voice of LET

Tags: passive-voice

**Active:** He let me go there.

**Passive:** I am let go there by him.

Or

I am allowed to go there by him.

Which 1 is correct?
Can we use [BE(am/is/are)+LET+VERB] -this structure in a sentence?

Comment: While passivizing, can 'let' become 'allow'?  Another point is 'let' can be present or past tense, since it has let/let/let in the pre/past/ p.participle forms.

Comment: 'I am let go there by him' is ungrammatical. 'I was let go by the sailor' uses the transitive multiword verb 'let go' = 'release' (though not totally interchangeable).